# List of Entries for Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

i am just getting started with Tkinter and want to create a simple input GUI for a Sudokusolver.
The problem is, that i cant create a list of lists with the 9*9 inputs for the sudoku. Everytime i want to access the data in grid, eg. grid[0][0] it outputs grid[8][0], so always the last row...
My code so far is:

```
from tkinter import *

grid = []
row = []
board = []

for i in range(9):
    row.append(0)
for n in range(9):
    grid.append(row)
    board.append(row)


def entry_copy():
    print(grid[1][1].get())
    for k in range(9):
        for l in range(9):
            pass


tkFenster = Tk()
tkFenster.title('Sudoku')
for i in range(9):
    for n in range(9):
        grid[i][n] = Entry(master=tkFenster, bg='white', width='5')
        grid[i][n].grid(row=i, column=n, padx='5', pady='8', sticky='ew')
        grid[i][n].insert(END, i + n)
button_copy = Button(master=tkFenster, text='Fertig!', width='5', bg='#FBD975', command=entry_copy)
button_copy.grid(row=9, column=4, padx='5', pady='5')

tkFenster.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that when you create grid/board each row isn't a copy of the previous row, it IS the same list as the previous row. Python doesn't create a new list, it just references to the original list.

Subsequently if you change column 2 on one row, the other rows will also contain that same value in column 2.

Consider using something like the code below to create your 2-D lists

```
board = [[0]*9 for i in range(9)]
```

Now when you change the value on one row, it doesn't affect the others.